# How to select some sublist in a list of list?

Tags: replacement, filtering, list-manipulation

Hopping to be clear, I ask this question after some hour of unsucceeded work
I have this list

```
a={{{0., 0.5, 0.4}, {-0.5, 0., -0.1}, {-0.4, 0.1, 
   0.}}, {{0., -0.5, -0.1}, {0.5, 0., 0.4}, {0.1, -0.4, 0.}}, {{0., 
   0., -0.6}, {0., 0., -0.6}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.}}}
```

associated with its sign matrix

```
b={{{0, 1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {-1, 1, 0}}, {{0, -1, -1}, {1, 0, 
        1}, {1, -1, 0}}, {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 0}}}
```

The first task is to replace all the sublists in `b` by the sum of their element to arrive to

```
{{2,-2,0},{-2,2,0},{-1,-1,2}}
```

Then in `a` I want to keep only the elements corresponding to 2 in fact the length of the row minus 1 that is as a final result

```
c={{{0., 0.5, 0.4}}, {{0.5, 0., 0.4}}, {{0.6, 0.6, 0.}}}
```

and to finish I want to delete the 0 in c.

I have tried with `Select`, but obviously all the pure function I have tried fails. Incidentely I wonder if there is a simple way, without transposing to find the sum of all the sublists of a list.

Comment: I'd normally retag, but I think I'm more interested in hearing you explain why you think this is a calculus problem.

Comment: Your perfectly true it's an algebra problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map[Total, b, {2}]
(* {{2, -2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}, {-1, -1, 2}} *)

c = Extract[a, Position[Map[Total, b, {2}], 2]]
(* {{0., 0.5, 0.4}, {0.5, 0., 0.4}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.}} *)

DeleteCases[c, 0., {2}]
(* {{0.5, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.6}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

A variation of existing answers:

```
b = Sign[a];

Join @@@ Pick[a, Unitize[b]*Total[b, {3}], 2]
```

> ```
> {{0.5, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.6}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Total[b, {3}]
```

> {{2, -2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}, {-1, -1, 2}}

```
Pick[a, Total[b, {3}], 2] == c
```

> True

```
Pick[a, Total[b, {3}], 2] /. 0 | 0. -> Nothing
```

> {{{0.5, 0.4}}, {{0.5, 0.4}}, {{0.6, 0.6}}}

Comment: @bbgodfrey It looks like he missed the final deletion of zeros, but otherwise isn't it as requested?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I may have been hasty in my comment.

Comment: Just for fun, a variation of the Pick method given by Coolwater & Mr Wizard: `b // Total[#, {3}] & // Pick[a, #, 2] & // Pick[#, Unitize@#, 1] &`

Answer (score 2):

```
Pick[#, Positive[Abs[#]]] &[Pick[a, Total[b, {3}], 2]]
```

> {{{0.5, 0.4}}, {{0.5, 0.4}}, {{0.6, 0.6}}}

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the `Unitize` usage from the page:

```
Map[Select[AllTrue[NonNegative]], a] // Pick[#, Unitize[#], 1] &
```

> {{{0.5, 0.4}}, {{0.5, 0.4}}, {{0.6, 0.6}}}

For some time, I tried variations around these ideas as well:

```
f = Pick[#, Map[Total@*Sign]@#, 2] &
f /@ a // Pick[#, Unitize@#, 1] &
```

or the equivalent:

```
Composition[Map[f], Pick[#, Unitize[#], 1] &][a]
```